# Huges number of images (500,000) in one android app How to?

Tags: android, image

I have 100,000 images each with a size of 15KB. I saved the name of the image and path of the images in the sqllite db and images are saved outside the db. The name of the image and id is displayed in the app and there is an option "img" icon next to the image name. When the user taps on the "img" icon then the image is displayed. Only one image at a time can be displayed. Is this possible? If so how can I accomplish? What is the best way?

Thanks in advance
Sravani

Comment: please post what you try?

Comment: there are list 100,000 names which are displayed, each name has an id associated with the name. The name of image is saved with the id outside the sql lite database in a folder which will be part of the app. When the user taps on the name a new screen is displayed which shows the image associated with that id. The image has some details associated with that name.

Comment: And what problems have you had with your code?

Comment: are you getting out of memory error, your apk size is exceeding limit, you are seeing performance issues?

Comment: The total size of all the images will come to 1.5GB and if I exclude the images the size of my app is 10mb. All these images are static and are used only for display purpose and no need for any future updates. The problem is the size of the apk will be more than the 50MB limit and how does it affect the performance of the app.

Comment: Currently I have only a sample of 10 images and testing with these is working perfectly. I am in the process of acquiring those images. Before acquiring those images I want to know if it is really possible to have all those 100,000 images with in the app or do I have any other options. Since I don't have all the images I don't know what issues I might run into.